# TinyMCE: delete ../ by images link

Tags: tinymce

I use TinyMCE Version 2.1 for my panel.

Sorry, how can I remove from the links of the images this symbol "../"?

`<img src="../images/nameimage.jpg"...>`

I would like these links:

`<img src="https://www.site.it/images/nameimage.jpg"...>`

and NO this link:

`<img src="../images/nameimage.jpg"...>`

Thanks a lot ;)

Alexander

Comment: Please review your question after you post it ... as you had created it none of the HTML was visible.  I have edited it to fix that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in your init function

```
tinymce.init({  
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    convert_urls : true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several configuration options that allow you to adjust how TinyMCE handles URLs:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/url-handling/

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer.

This is the file that contain variable document_base_url

[https://ufile.io/c0xja][1]


  [1]: https://ufile.io/c0xja

but I could not get the desired result.


Can you help me?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Sorry the link is not correct, you can download the file from here : https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: You appear to have tried to send me the `tinymce.min.js` file - you never change that file directly.  You add configuration options to your TinyMCE configuration (where you use `init({})` to setup the editor to add these configuration options.