# Path link images on TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I use TinyMCE Version 2.1 for my panel.

Sorry, how can I remove from the links of the images this symbol "../"?

I would like these links:

```
<img src="https://www.site.it/images/nameimage.jpg"...>
```

and NO this link:

```
<img src="../images/nameimage.jpg"...>
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Alexander

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TinyMCE: delete ../ by images link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538875/tinymce-delete-by-images-link)

Comment: Please don't repost the same question multiple times ... you should delete/close this and stick with your original question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538875/tinymce-delete-by-images-link